# Java - How would you make a UI thread communicate with logic/data thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, communication

I am programming a small game. I already implemented my logic in one Java project and it is working correctly (Handling inputs with a Scanner in console).

Now, next step is to create a UI and to replace my Scanner inputs by the clicks generated by the user at certain positions.

I do not really know how to do, because I need the UI thread, and thread from the logic. However, I do not really know how to orchestrate the different method calls and how to start the program (Because I might have 2 Main methods).

What I thought was to move the main function in the UI thread, starting the program. Then it handles user clicks on the menu, and start a thread to launch the logic of the game. **1 - Is that correct ?**

Because the game is played by turn, I need to loop the following scenario : 
 - User clicks, it send data to the logic thread (**2 - UI should wait, but is that possible ?**)
- Logic thread computes a result and update the UI (**3 - How ? By returning the data to the UI thread directly ?**)
- Logic thread waits. UI thread wait another click, and send it to logic thread, etc...

If I do not reuse the logic thread, the data contained in the logic thread will be lost. So I think I need to keep the logic thread alive

**To resume : How to handle thread (and their communication) between UI with my and my logic/data module ?**

Thank you !

Comment: You need to restructure your program to be event driven rather than imperative as your code is now. You don't appear to need a logic thread at all and most likely having one is just confusing.

Comment: By event driven, are you talking of something like Implicit invocation style ? 
You suggest that I should keep only UI thread, and it will create many small threads to compute a result in the logic part ? (If that's what you meant, where/how should I keep data for the current state of the game?)
Thanks

Comment: The Event Loop Thread is single threaded. When an event occurs it is added to a queue for processing. The event loop processes each event in turn in one thread. What you implement is callbacks for code to be executed when each event happens.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much

Comment: Why do you need a separate game thread if you're doing turn based game play? If you want to use multiple threads, then you need to establish some kind of observer pattern, maybe using a blocking queue (producer/consumer pattern) and/or monitor locks